# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, nszombies

I sometimes get EXC_BAD_ACCESS without knowing the source.I enabled Zombies and this is now what I get on the console:

```
2018-08-27 18:37:41.785523+0530 MyProject[3419:1228271] *** -[MyProject.VideoLibrary retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x103078200
```

VideoLibrary is the name of controller and I am not sending any retain messages. How do I go further to identify the issue and fix it? I am using Swift 4.0 if that matters.

Comment: Have you disabled ARC? - Do you see any Zombies? If you type 'info malloc-history <memLocation>' (0x103078200 in your example), what do you see?

Comment: I am using ARC. How do I see Zombies?

Comment: Run your app, wait for crash, and type into debugger 'info malloc-history <memLocation>' where memLocation is the address of the Zombie. (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544)

Comment: crash is hard to reproduce, I will come back with questions as soon as I reproduce it again.

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to have more information about a crash, I create an exception breakpoint.

You can add one from the breakpoint navigator by clicking on the "+".

When added, edit it and add `po $arg1` for action.  This will print information about the exception.